# AutocompleteTextView suggetion list not showing

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I want to show list user name and their phone number from the server as a suggestion below AutoCompleteTextView. I don't want a filter because I am already getting filter result from the server. I added TextWatcher on AutoComleteTextView on every text change it will call API. I made custom Adapter but it is not showing anything.

**ArrayList declared as global**

```
ArrayList<NameModel> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
AutoCompleteAdapter autoCompleteAdapter;
```

**onCreate**

```
 autoCompleteAdapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter(this,nameList);
 txtNumber.setAdapter(autoCompleteAdapter);

    txtNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String number = s.toString();
            if (number.matches("^[0-9]*$") && number.length() == 10){
                btnAdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else {
                btnAdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                GetNames(s);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

**GetNames()**

```
nameList.clear();
    autoCompleteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    String params = inst_id+"/?name="+text;
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, getResources().getString(R.string.ipmain)+GET_NAME_URL+params, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = jsonObject.getString("first_name")+" "+jsonObject.getString("last_name");
                    String role = jsonObject.getString("role");
                    String number = jsonObject.getString("phone_number");

                    NameModel nameModel = new NameModel(name,role,number);
                    nameList.add(nameModel);
                }
                autoCompleteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Adapter- which is the subclass of parent**

```
private class AutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NameModel> {
    Context cntx;
    ArrayList<NameModel> listGlobal;

    AutoCompleteAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<NameModel> list) {
        super(context,R.layout.item_attendance,list);
        cntx = context;
        listGlobal = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_attendance, parent, false);
        }
        TextView txtName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        TextView txtRole = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtGender);
        TextView txtPhone = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);

        txtName.setText(listGlobal.get(position).getName());
        txtRole.setText(listGlobal.get(position).getRole());
        txtPhone.setText(listGlobal.get(position).getNumber());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.d("Adpter List:",String.valueOf(listGlobal.size()));
        Log.d("Main List:",String.valueOf(nameList.size()));

        return listGlobal.size();

    }
}
```

**crashing on second letter enter(not showing anything on first letter enter)**

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:349)
    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.buildImeCompletions(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1241)
    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1201)
    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1084)
    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.-wrap2(AutoCompleteTextView.java)
    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$PopupDataSetObserver$1.run(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1409)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to revise the following

**1.** After doing the remote StringRequest make sure you update the AutoCompleteAdapter with the new nameList.

**2.** make sure array list has values before calling autoCompleteAdapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter(this,nameList);

Comment: Already adding data in nameList and after that notifyingDataSetChanged();

Comment: well , i don't see where you do update your adapter ,i assume you either have method inside the adapter  public void updateList(List<String> newlist) {
    nameList.clear();
    nameList.addAll(newlist);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
} or you do the remote server call inside the adapter itself ?

Comment: where is the method GetNames() defined ?

Comment: inside parent class

Comment: so are you assuming that nameList is going to be updated inside the adapter because it is a global variable ? if no fine , if yes it won't work because Java is Pass by Value and Not Pass by Reference

Comment: No Adapter have listGlobal and listGlobal have data of namelist. and in adapter it works with listGlobal variable.

Comment: And in Adapter class i am checking size of nameList and globalList, both have same size means list have data but not showing it

Answer (score 0):

try to invalidate and restart android studio.

or

delete .gradle, .iml, .idea files and rebuild your project

Comment: no something wrong in code. Itried ur solution but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are having problems because you are using an ArrayAdapter. An ArrayAdapter keeps its own list and works on that so when you supply a list in the constructor the adapter creates a copy and uses that to populate the views. When you update your list object, the adapter's copy is not updated but since you override the getCount method and return a non zero value, the adapter tries to fetch an item from an empty list.

Solution: You should use a BaseAdapter instead. Or if you want to use an ArrayAdapter, you should modify the adapter's list using ArrayAdapter.add(), ArrayAdapter.clear() etc instead.